# is check nil value this way correct?

Tags: iphone, null

hi i just want to know if this is correct, can we check for nil this way-`if(self.spinner==nil)`?

thanks

```
if (self.spinner == nil) {
    self.spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    //.............needs work.............  
    CGRect center = [self.view bounds];
    CGSize winCenter = center.size;
    CGPoint pont = CGPointMake(winCenter.width/2,winCenter.height/2);
    //CGPoint pont = CGPointMake(10,40);
    [spinner setCenter:pont];
    [self.view addSubview:spinner];
    [self.spinner startAnimating];
} else {
    [self.spinner startAnimating];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, checking against `nil` is absolutely valid. Somewhere deep within headers, `nil` is defined as `(id)0`, which means you can use pointer equality to compare it to any Objective-C object.

An astute observer will realize that since `nil` is zero and that Objective-C conditional control structures (`if`, `while` and the like) accept any `int`-like data type, using an object pointer as the condition itself will pass if the object is non-`nil` and fail if the object is `nil`:

```
if (self.spinner) // implicitly checks that self.spinner is non-nil
if (!self.spinner) // implicitly checks that self.spinner is nil
```

Depending on your background as a programmer, you may or may not like this feature. But it works just as much as comparing to `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's correct. And you can even write shorter:

```
if ( !self.spinner ) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but I'd change it slightly:

```
if (!self.spinner) {
    self.spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] ...
    ...
}
// Do this outside the test, thus avoiding the else.
[self.spinner startAnimating];
```